# How to block an app from launching in android at system level?

Tags: android, systems-programming

I want to know the exact method which invokes/starts all the apps. I basically want to block a certain set of apps using xposed module. Its ok if the app icon is visible but the app should not be launched after clicking on it. To be precise nothing should happen when the user clicks on the app icon.

So I want to know where the source code which invokes the apps.

PS : I would also like to know if there is any way to hide the icon of the app as well.

Comment: remove `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` from app's manifest?

Comment: `Launcher` app can do this magic. But if you want to hide other apps which are not yours then you can't touch their manifest file @anishsane

Comment: no i want to block existing apps. say i want to block facebook. how should i block it. i mean it shouldnt launch only. i want to block it at the system level.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own launcher app and replace it with the ones running on mobile phones.

You can check the sources of [Laucher](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher) and [Laucher2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2) currently running on Android system.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I am little new to xposed framework. I had few queries. 
1. In which source file and which function is responsible to launch an app.
2. If I modify launcher using xposed and block few apps, will those apps still open in other launcher say (Go Launcher ex)

I want to block the app at such a level that those apps cannot be opened from anywhere at any cost. They shouldn't exist in the memory itself. The purpose of hiding them is to block them from the root level so that they can never be launched.